# What is the total charge Q of 1 m³ of copper?

Tags: charge, electron, copper

I was wondering if I can calculate the total charge Q of 1 m<sup>3</sup> of copper, see my calculation in the picture below. Is this correct?

[image]

**The correct solution (thanks to the community in the comments below):**

My solution above for Q is wrong! The correct solution is Q = 0 since there is the same amount of protons in 1 m<sup>3</sup> of copper, see the calculation below. I hope it is correct now.

[image]

Comment: You only have 3 significant digits for `d`, so having more than that in the final answer is mostly meaningless. And you are forgetting an equal number of protons, that would most likely get a total net charge of `~ 0`.

Comment: You are calculating the charge of the electrons, not the charge of the copper.

Comment: Under no external influence copper (and any other material) would have an equal amount of protons and electrons. So the total charge of any volume of copper is 0

Comment: 8.46*10^28, is that total electrons, or conduction electrons? It might have been nice to work that from first principles. In normal copper, that total number of electrons will be matched by the same number of protons, rendering the total charge approximately zero.

Comment: If you remove all the electrons from one cubic meter of copper, then the resulting (insanely highly) charged plasma that results will explode violently from electrostatic repulsion, and you won't have one cubic meter of copper any more -- you'll have an expanding cloud of cuprous plasma in the center of a vast area of devastation.

Comment: Thanks @all for your support. I added a new screenshot with the new solution. I hope now it is correct. Best Regards

Comment: How can you have any charge across a perfect conductor reading 0V?

Comment: @Marco Cu is \$m=63.546\,\text{u}\$ and density at \$20\,^\circ\$C is \$\rho= 8.96\,\frac{\text{g}}{\text{cc}}\$. Avogadro's is \$N_A=6.02214076\times 10^{23}\:\text{mol}^{-1}\$. So \$1\:\text{cc}\$ of copper has \$\frac{N_A\,\cdot\, \rho}{m}\approx 8.49\times 10^{^{22}}\,\frac{\text{atoms}}{\text{cc}}\$. Assuming 1 conduction band electron per atom, \$1\:\text{m}^3\$ would have \$8.49\times 10^{^{28}}\$ of them.

Comment: @Marco But that's wrong. An integral over the electron state density and Fermi-Dirac distribution factors yields \$\left[\frac{8\pi\,\sqrt{2\,m_{\large e}^3}}{h^3}\right]\left[\frac23\sqrt{E_{F}^{\:\:3}}\vphantom{\frac{\sqrt{2\,m_{\large e}^3}}{h^3}}\right]= 8.411\times 10^{22}\,\frac{\text{cband electrons}}{\text{cc}}\$ or \$8.411\times 10^{^{28}}\$ conduction band electrons in a cubic meter. (\$m_{\large e}\$ is the electron mass and \$E_{F}=7.00 \:\text{eV}\$ for Cu.) You are using all those decimal points in your writing. So there was a need to add corrections.

Comment: Hello @periblepsis, thanks for your comment. did I understand you right: I should change in my solution the value for the amount of electrons from  <8.46x10^28> to <8.411x10^28>? Thx and BR Marco

Comment: @Marco There are 29 protons per atom of copper. Which means 29 electrons for each, as well. As it turns out about 99% of the copper atoms at 20 C will have one of its electrons present in the conduction band. (So that copper is conductive.) Copper is still neutral in the sense that there are, to such a close approximation that the differences are totally irrelevant to discuss, exactly the same number of electrons as protons. It's just that some of them are "free enough" to move about a bit. (Some of the copper (about half) will have one more neutron than the other half.)

Answer (score 0):

All the charge is stored on the dielectric surrounding the conductor by the voltage detected with respect to a nearby conductor.

The conductors cannot store any charge!
Only transfer it!

Comment: Hello @Hoagie, thanks for reply. You mean that for example air (dielectric material) can be charged? BR Marco